# how to add class when I reached specific section and remove when it passes the section

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-events

I want to change the scrollTop to specific section and else to remove class if it surpass the section.
I'm a beginner, any help will be appreciated. Thank you! :)

```
        $(document).on("scroll", function () {


            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 5000) {
                $(".span-s").addClass("shrink");
            } else {
                $(".span-s").removeClass("shrink");
            }

        });
```

I tried this but the else doesn't remove the class when it surpass the section.

```
    var bottom = $('.construction').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > bottom) {
            $('.sidebar_list').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.sidebar_list').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an Intersection Observer. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is in viewport

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.constructor').isInViewport()) {
        $('.sidebar_list').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.sidebar_list').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the help I really appreciate this. I'll give this a try and get back to you after.